# Difference between .save and .saveAndFlush()

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I can't understand the differences in real cases between the .save() and .saveAndFlush() method.
When I use a JpaRepository with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and I want to simply persist my Entity, is there really a difference between which of them I use?
Can someone make some example to understand the differences and which I should use?
Thank you!

Comment: This is surely helpful! If I understand it right, I should use the .save() if I have a lot of RAM, so I can leave jpa free to decide when flush the data. If I need to keep the memory free I have to call the .saveAndFlush(), but the performance are a little worst because jpa need the time to persist the object.
Is this correct?

Comment: You would only see a meaningful difference in performance if you are planning to do a really, I mean really huge operation within a single transaction hence It is not related to performance at all, one of the main points I know on when to use one or another, use saveAndFlush if you need to handle constraint exceptions right then and there. Say you have a method with 5 operations, all saving data. If you want to prevent 2,3,4,5 from running because a possible error on 1, you would use saveAndFlush as it would try to write the data to the DB making the validations beforehand over at the end of 5

Comment: Here another example based on above one that might illustrate better 1-5 all saves data to the database, though process 2 also sends an api call (idempotent) to a third part, 3 to 5 also saves data to database and also processes files and save to aws S3, now all of this depends on the first DB save on process 1 to be correct. So if you use `save` on process 1 all of this would happen and you would only have the error at the end of the transaction, hence you would have to revert every other step from integrated stuff. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Using saveAndFlush on process one could possible prevent that as you would receive the database error right there, unique constraint for example.